# set Combobox ItemsSource BindingContext to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding

I have a ListView, in which I placed some ComboBoxes as following :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCategories" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListCategoryPart}" SelectionChanged="ListViewCategories_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header ="{x:Static p:Resources.Machine}" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListCutMachines}"
                SelectedValuePath="ID"
                SelectedValue="{Binding DefaultCutMachine, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="100"
                />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

DefaultCutMachine is part of my object `CategoryPart`(Items listed in ListView).

But what I would like is take the Combobox ItemsSource not from my objects, but from my ViewModel.

How can I bind all my Items Comboboxes ItemsSource not from the Items, but from my ViewModel?(I read about "BindingContext", but don't find how to do it on a ComboBox ItemsSource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to create a binding that has a `RelativeSource` with the proper `DataContext` of your ViewModel.

Here is an example:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.ListCutMachines}"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly, thanks. Could you please just explain me the part `AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}` didn't get how it works, thanks

Comment: `AncestorType` in the `RelativeSource` is telling the binding to look up the visual tree, and find the first element that is a `ListView`. So when the binding tries to resolve `Path=DataContext.ListCutMachines`, it will do it against the data context object on the first ListView it finds. I hope that makes sense.